# How to find list of Shave n haircut shapes in Maya and its shader list connection using python

Tags: python, maya, mel, pymel

I need to print each shave shape and its assigned shader name if assigned. Please help in this.

```
import os
import maya.cmds as cmds
shave_list = cmds.ls(type='shaveHair')
cmds.select(cl=True)
a = 0
list_texture = []
while a < len(shave_list):
    file_list = cmds.listconnections(shave_list[a],type="file")
    a+=1
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Your question is not clear, Did you want to find the shader / file or all networks ? Please send the example of the your result

Comment: Sorry for the confusion..
I need to print each shave shape and its assigned shader name if any

Answer (score 0):

If you want the shader name for a shape:

```
def shader_from_shape(shape):
    sg = cmds.listConnections(shape, type='shadingEngine')
    if sg:
        return cmds.listConnections(sg[0]  + ".surfaceShader")
```

and to get the shaders for all hair shapes:

```
for shape in cmds.ls(type='shaveHair'):
    print shape, shader_from_shape(shape)
```

if the shape has no shader attached, it should print `None` for the shader. This won't give correct results if the shape has more than one shader - I'm not sure if that's possible or not.